# Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token Vert.x

Tags: kotlin, jackson, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I'm using `Kotlin` and `Vert.x` and I have:

```
data class Product(
    var id: UUID? = UUID.randomUUID(),
    var name: String? = null,

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    var pictures: JsonArray? = JsonArray()
)
```

and I'm trying to POST an `Array` of objects in `pictures`. My JSON in request body is this:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "pictures": [{"test": "a"}]
}
```

When I send an `Object` inside the `Array` like above, I receive this error:

```
[ERROR] 2020-01-02 13:04:26.519 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] Route - io.vertx.core.json.DecodeException: Failed to decode:Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object>` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{
        "name": "Test",
        "pictures": [{"test": "a"}]
}
"; line: 8, column: 15] (through reference chain: br.com.test.api.product.Product["pictures"]->io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray["list"])
```

But if I send an empty `Array` like this, its works:

```
{
        "name": "Test",
        "pictures": []
}
```

and I receive correct response:

```
{"id":"a6d2d319-42a9-4d4a-b16a-6bf4eb76e36d","name":"Test","pictures":[]}
```

So the question is, how can I post an `Array` of `Objects` in my client? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to have an object that will match the shape of the objects in the 'pictures' array, then the following should work:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor
import lombok.Data
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
class Product {

    var name: String? = null
    var pictures: List<Picture>? = null

    @Data
    class Picture {

        var test: String? = null

    }

}
```

And example use working for me:

```
@Test
fun deserializeProduct() {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val sample: String = "{" +
            "    \"name\": \"Test\"," +
            "    \"pictures\": [{\"test\": \"a\"}]" +
            "}"

    val json = mapper.readValue(sample, Product::class.java);
    assertEquals("a", json.pictures?.get(0)?.test)
}
```

If the contents of the objects in the pictures array wont be the same shape every time, then it may be worth making the List of pictures a Map:

```
var pictures: Map<String, *>?
```

Then you can achieve the following payloads:

```
@Test
fun deserializeProduct() {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    val sample: String = "{" +
            "    \"name\": \"Test\"," +
            "    \"pictures\": [{\"test\": \"a\"}, {\"differentKey\":\"b\",\"differentKey2\":1}]" +
            "}"

    val json = mapper.readValue(sample, Product::class.java);
    assertEquals("a", json.pictures?.get(0)?.get("test"))
    assertEquals("b", json.pictures?.get(1)?.get("differentKey"))
    assertEquals(1, json.pictures?.get(1)?.get("differentKey2"))
}
```